# Azure worker role throws after EF/Odata Nuget upgrades

Tags: entity-framework, azure, clr, nuget, reflection.emit

Have an Azure project with web and worker roles.
Recently upgraded all nuget packages (EF went from 6.0 to 6.1 among other things).
The web role seems to be fine
The worker roles is not able to do much. Keep getting various exceptions coming from framework code:

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary

Additional information: Duplicate type name within an assembly.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Verbose: 502 : A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
Role instance status check succeeded: Ready
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Critical: 1 : Unhandled Exception:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentException: Duplicate type name within an assembly.
   at System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder.CheckTypeNameConflict(String strTypeName, Type enclosingType)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderData.CheckTypeNameConflict(String strTypeName, TypeBuilder enclosingType)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.Init(String fullname, TypeAttributes attr, Type parent, Type[] interfaces, ModuleBuilder module, PackingSize iPackingSize, Int32 iTypeSize, TypeBuilder enclosingType)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder.DefineType(String name, TypeAttributes attr, Type parent, Type[] interfaces)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.ProxyTypeBuilder.get_TypeBuilder()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.ProxyTypeBuilder.CreateType(ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.BuildType(ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder, ClrEntityType ospaceEntityType, MetadataWorkspace workspace)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.TryCreateProxyType(EntityType ospaceEntityType, MetadataWorkspace workspace)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.GetProxyType(ClrEntityType ospaceEntityType, MetadataWorkspace workspace)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.Visit(EntityColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.EntityColumnMap.Accept[TResultType,TArgType](ColumnMapVisitorWithResults`2 visitor, TArgType arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.ProcessCollectionColumnMap(CollectionColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg, ColumnMap discriminatorColumnMap, Object discriminatorValue)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.ProcessCollectionColumnMap(CollectionColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.Visit(SimpleCollectionColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.SimpleCollectionColumnMap.Accept[TResultType,TArgType](ColumnMapVisitorWithResults`2 visitor, TArgType arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslateColumnMap[T](ColumnMap columnMap, MetadataWorkspace workspace, SpanIndex spanIndex, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Boolean valueLayer)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslateColumnMap(Translator translator, Type elementType, ColumnMap columnMap, MetadataWorkspace workspace, SpanIndex spanIndex, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Boolean valueLayer)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Span span, IEnumerable`1 compiledQueryParameters, AliasGenerator aliasGenerator)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.Retail.Cloud.MediaProcessing.ProcessNewItems() in c:\TFS\Trunk\Cloud\Cloud.Processing\Services\MediaProcessing.cs:line 39
   at Microsoft.Retail.Cloud.Process.AssetGatherer.Run() in c:\TFS\Trunk\Cloud\Cloud.Processing\AssetGatherer.cs:line 46
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.StartRoleInternal()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.StartRole()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Implementation.Loader.RoleRuntimeBridge.<StartRole>b__2()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.dll
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unhandled exception</Description><AppDomain>RdRuntime</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslateColumnMap(Translator translator, Type elementType, ColumnMap columnMap, MetadataWorkspace workspace, SpanIndex spanIndex, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Boolean valueLayer)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Span span, IEnumerable`1 compiledQueryParameters, AliasGenerator aliasGenerator)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.&lt;&gt;c_*DisplayClass7.&lt;GetResults&gt;b*_6()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.&lt;&gt;c_*DisplayClass7.&lt;GetResults&gt;b*_5()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.&lt;System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable&lt;T&gt;.GetEnumerator&gt;b_*0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.Retail.Cloud.MediaProcessing.ProcessNewItems() in c:\TFS\Trunk\Cloud\Cloud.Processing\Services\MediaProcessing.cs:line 39
   at Microsoft.Retail.Cloud.Process.AssetGatherer.Run() in c:\TFS\Trunk\Cloud\Cloud.Processing\AssetGatherer.cs:line 46
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.StartRoleInternal()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.StartRole()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Implementation.Loader.RoleRuntimeBridge.&lt;StartRole&gt;b*_2()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---&gt; System.ArgumentException: Duplicate type name within an assembly.
   at System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder.CheckTypeNameConflict(String strTypeName, Type enclosingType)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderData.CheckTypeNameConflict(String strTypeName, TypeBuilder enclosingType)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.Init(String fullname, TypeAttributes attr, Type parent, Type[] interfaces, ModuleBuilder module, PackingSize iPackingSize, Int32 iTypeSize, TypeBuilder enclosingType)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder.DefineType(String name, TypeAttributes attr, Type parent, Type[] interfaces)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.ProxyTypeBuilder.get_TypeBuilder()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.ProxyTypeBuilder.CreateType(ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.BuildType(ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder, ClrEntityType ospaceEntityType, MetadataWorkspace workspace)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.TryCreateProxyType(EntityType ospaceEntityType, MetadataWorkspace workspace)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.GetProxyType(ClrEntityType ospaceEntityType, MetadataWorkspace workspace)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.Visit(EntityColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.EntityColumnMap.Accept[TResultType,TArgType](ColumnMapVisitorWithResults`2 visitor, TArgType arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.ProcessCollectionColumnMap(CollectionColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg, ColumnMap discriminatorColumnMap, Object discriminatorValue)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.ProcessCollectionColumnMap(CollectionColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.Visit(SimpleCollectionColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.SimpleCollectionColumnMap.Accept[TResultType,TArgType](ColumnMapVisitorWithResults`2 visitor, TArgType arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslateColumnMap[T](ColumnMap columnMap, MetadataWorkspace workspace, SpanIndex spanIndex, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Boolean valueLayer)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslateColumnMap(Translator translator, Type elementType, ColumnMap columnMap, MetadataWorkspace workspace, SpanIndex spanIndex, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Boolean valueLayer)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Span span, IEnumerable`1 compiledQueryParameters, AliasGenerator aliasGenerator)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.&amp;lt;&amp;gt;c__DisplayClass7.&amp;lt;GetResults&amp;gt;b__6()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.&amp;lt;&amp;gt;c__DisplayClass7.&amp;lt;GetResults&amp;gt;b__5()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.&amp;lt;System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable&amp;lt;T&amp;gt;.GetEnumerator&amp;gt;b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.Retail.Cloud.MediaProcessing.ProcessNewItems() in c:\TFS\Trunk\Cloud\Cloud.Processing\Services\MediaProcessing.cs:line 39
   at Microsoft.Retail.Cloud.Process.AssetGatherer.Run() in c:\TFS\Trunk\Cloud\Cloud.Processing\AssetGatherer.cs:line 46
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.StartRoleInternal()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.StartRole()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Implementation.Loader.RoleRuntimeBridge.&amp;lt;StartRole&amp;gt;b__2()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()</ExceptionString><InnerException><ExceptionType>System.ArgumentException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Duplicate type name within an assembly.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder.CheckTypeNameConflict(String strTypeName, Type enclosingType)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderData.CheckTypeNameConflict(String strTypeName, TypeBuilder enclosingType)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.Init(String fullname, TypeAttributes attr, Type parent, Type[] interfaces, ModuleBuilder module, PackingSize iPackingSize, Int32 iTypeSize, TypeBuilder enclosingType)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder.DefineType(String name, TypeAttributes attr, Type parent, Type[] interfaces)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.ProxyTypeBuilder.get_TypeBuilder()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.ProxyTypeBuilder.CreateType(ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.BuildType(ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder, ClrEntityType ospaceEntityType, MetadataWorkspace workspace)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.TryCreateProxyType(EntityType ospaceEntityType, MetadataWorkspace workspace)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.GetProxyType(ClrEntityType ospaceEntityType, MetadataWorkspace workspace)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.Visit(EntityColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.EntityColumnMap.Accept[TResultType,TArgType](ColumnMapVisitorWithResults`2 visitor, TArgType arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.ProcessCollectionColumnMap(CollectionColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg, ColumnMap discriminatorColumnMap, Object discriminatorValue)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.ProcessCollectionColumnMap(CollectionColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.Visit(SimpleCollectionColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.SimpleCollectionColumnMap.Accept[TResultType,TArgType](ColumnMapVisitorWithResults`2 visitor, TArgType arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslateColumnMap[T](ColumnMap columnMap, MetadataWorkspace workspace, SpanIndex spanIndex, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Boolean valueLayer)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.ArgumentException: Duplicate type name within an assembly.
   at System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder.CheckTypeNameConflict(String strTypeName, Type enclosingType)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderData.CheckTypeNameConflict(String strTypeName, TypeBuilder enclosingType)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.Init(String fullname, TypeAttributes attr, Type parent, Type[] interfaces, ModuleBuilder module, PackingSize iPackingSize, Int32 iTypeSize, TypeBuilder enclosingType)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder.DefineType(String name, TypeAttributes attr, Type parent, Type[] interfaces)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.ProxyTypeBuilder.get_TypeBuilder()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.ProxyTypeBuilder.CreateType(ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.BuildType(ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder, ClrEntityType ospaceEntityType, MetadataWorkspace workspace)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.TryCreateProxyType(EntityType ospaceEntityType, MetadataWorkspace workspace)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.GetProxyType(ClrEntityType ospaceEntityType, MetadataWorkspace workspace)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.Visit(EntityColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.EntityColumnMap.Accept[TResultType,TArgType](ColumnMapVisitorWithResults`2 visitor, TArgType arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.ProcessCollectionColumnMap(CollectionColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg, ColumnMap discriminatorColumnMap, Object discriminatorValue)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.ProcessCollectionColumnMap(CollectionColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.Visit(SimpleCollectionColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.SimpleCollectionColumnMap.Accept[TResultType,TArgType](ColumnMapVisitorWithResults`2 visitor, TArgType arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslateColumnMap[T](ColumnMap columnMap, MetadataWorkspace workspace, SpanIndex spanIndex, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Boolean valueLayer)